# Apply hover effect in css

Tags: html, css

I have a react js application witch contains a select with a dropdown. I want to apply styles for 2 states: when the mouse hover the dropdown item and when the dropdown item is focused.

```css
.select__option.select__option--is-focused {
  background: blue;
}

.select__option:hover {
  background: gray;
}
```

Both styles work. If the user will navigate within dropdown with keyboard arrow (up/down) the will be applied `blue` color on the item, if he will hover the item will be applied `gray` color as background. 
 **ISSUE**: When user hover the focused item which has `blue` background, the hover color overrides the `blue`, but i want to not override blue color even the hover is applied over focused element, so the focused element should keep everytime its color. 
 How to fix that? 
 https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-y4zs8?file=/example.tsx:0-505

Comment: _"but i want to not override blue color even the hover is applied over focused element"_ - if nothing else helps, then just write a rule that does explicitly apply blue background when both conditions are met - the element has those class names, _and_ is hovered. `.select__option.select__option--is-focused:hover` (Can be combined with the existing first rule, by just listing both selector expressions comma separated.)

Comment: @CBroe, could you please the css codde? Because on my side does not work. Probably i dont do something right. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Just switch elements in place (so that later overwrites previous) or make `.select__option.select__option--is-focused:hover{background: blue}` as rule too

```css
.select__option:hover {
  background: gray;
}

.select__option.select__option--is-focused {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="select__option">
  .select__option
</div>
<div class="select__option select__option--is-focused">
  .select__option.select__option--is-focused
</div>
```

Comment: i tried in sanbox but after that the hover color is overriten by blue.

Comment: could you help? I want to keep for the rest of the options the hover effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `not()` pseudo class:

```
.select__option:not(.select__option--is-selected):hover {
  background: gray;
}
```

My bad, i gave the wrong class in the not(). updated it

Comment: after your changes i can not notice `gray` color. Could you help? I want to keep gray color for the rest of options.

Comment: @Asking - I have updated my answer, please check

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else helps, then just write a rule that does explicitly apply blue background color when both conditions are met - the element has those class names, and is hovered. You can combine both into one single rule, by simply listing both selector expressions comma separated.

```
.select__option.select__option--is-focused,
.select__option.select__option--is-focused:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```